# Java swing double buffering

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, double-buffering, jscrollbar

i just started using double buffering and everything worked just fine until i wanted to add a JScrollPane to the screen so i later on can do some camera movements. Everything shows up fine (my sprites) EXCEPT the ScrollBars of the JScrollPane. And i want them to be shown!

However if i resize the window, the scrollbars flicker, so i know they are there! I can even use them if i'm fast enough. How come they dont show up at rendering? :(

Here is a SSCCE of the problem:

```
public class BufferStrategyDemo extends JFrame
{
    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    private JPanel gameField;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public BufferStrategyDemo()
    {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.pack();
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);

        this.gameField = new JPanel();
        this.gameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 1400, 600 ));

        this.scroll = new JScrollPane( gameField );
        this.add( scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        this.setVisible( true );
        this.bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();

        setupGameFieldContent();

        new Renderer( this, scroll , bufferStrategy ).start();
    }

    // Add some contents to gameField that shows up fine
    private void setupGameFieldContent()
    {
        // For ( all my sprites )
        //      gameField.add( sprite );

    }

    private class Renderer extends Thread
    {
        private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
        private JFrame window;
        private JScrollPane scroll;
        private Image imageOfGameField;

        public Renderer( JFrame window, JScrollPane scroll, BufferStrategy bufferStrategy )
        {
            this.bufferStrategy = bufferStrategy;
            this.window = window;
            this.scroll = scroll;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while ( true )
            {
                Graphics g = null;
                try 
                {
                    g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
                    drawSprites(g);
                } 
                finally { g.dispose(); }

                bufferStrategy.show(); // Shows everything except the scrollbars..
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); 

                try { Thread.sleep( 1000/60 ) ; } 
                catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        }

        private void drawSprites( Graphics g )
        {
            Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;

            //Also tried using the JPanels (gameField) createImage with same result
            imageOfGameField = this.scroll.createImage(800, 600 ); 
            Graphics screen = (Graphics2D)imageOfGameField.getGraphics();

            /**
             * For all my sprites, draw on the image
            for ( Sprite current : sprites )
                screen.drawImage( current.getImage(), current.getX(), current.getY(), current.getWidth() , current.getHeight(), null);
            */

            g2d.drawImage( imageOfGameField, 0, 0 , null );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Making a game where theese sizes is the current level width and height. I want to show 800 pixels in the screen, then scroll further if the player reaches any edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing is performed on whole frame area, not on `gameField`. Actually, the only cause of temporary `JScrollPane` appearing is that it calls `paintImmediately` somewhere in mouse-drag handler.

The first thing that comes to mind is to replace `JPanel` with `Canvas`, as I_Love_Thinking wrote, then get `bufferStategy` from that canvas instance and use it for rendering. But unfortunately it not works as expected. Lightweight `JScrollPane` can't properly drive heavyweight `Canvas`. Canvas refuses to draw content outside area (0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height). This is known [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6220186) and it will not fixed. Mixing mixing heavyweight components with lightweight is bad idea.

Replacing `JScrollPane` with heavyweight [`ScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/ScrollPane.html) seems working. Almost. There are noticeable rendering artifacts on scroll bars under some circumstances.

At this point, I've decided to stop beating the wall and give up. Scroll panes are the source of numerous problems and not worth to use for lazy scrolling. It is time to look on scrolling from another view. The `Canvas` *is not* game field itself, but window that we use to observe game world. This is well-known rendering strategy in gamedev. The size of canvas is exactly as observable area. When scrolling needed, we just render the world with some offset. The value for offset may be taken from some external scrollbar.

I suggest next changes:

1. Throw away `JScrollPane`
2. Add canvas directly to frame.
3. Add single horizontal `JScrollBar` under canvas.
4. Use value of scrollbar to shift rendering.

The example is based on your code. This implementation not respects resizing of frame. In real life some places need to be synchronized with size of viewport (that what scrollpane did before for us). Also, example violates Swing threading rules and reads value of  scrollbar from rendering thread.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class BufferStrategyDemo extends JFrame {
    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
    private Canvas gameField;
    private JScrollBar scroll;

    public BufferStrategyDemo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        gameField = new Canvas();
        gameField.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        gameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 580));
        getContentPane().add(gameField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        scroll = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 20));
        scroll.setMaximum(1400 - 800); // image width - viewport width
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.pack();

        gameField.createBufferStrategy(2);
        bufferStrategy = gameField.getBufferStrategy();

        new Renderer().start();
    }

    private class Renderer extends Thread {
        private BufferedImage imageOfGameField;

        public Renderer() {
            // NOTE: image size is fixed now, but better to bind image size to the size of viewport
            imageOfGameField = new BufferedImage(1400, 580, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Graphics g = null;
                try {
                    g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
                    drawSprites(g);
                } finally {
                    g.dispose();
                }

                bufferStrategy.show(); 
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }

        private void drawSprites(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            Graphics g2d2 = imageOfGameField.createGraphics();
            g2d2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); // clear background
            g2d2.fillRect(0, 0, 1400, 580); // again, fixed width/height only for SSCCE
            g2d2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            int shift = -scroll.getValue(); // here it is - get shift value

            g2d2.fillRect(100 + shift, 100, 20, 20); // i am ugly black sprite
            g2d2.fillRect(900 + shift, 100, 20, 20); // i am other black sprite
                                                     // located outside of default view

            g2d.drawImage(imageOfGameField, 0, 0, null);
            
            g2d2.dispose();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                BufferStrategyDemo mf = new BufferStrategyDemo();
                mf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And [another example](http://pastebin.com/aG3dTntm), mostly based on code from [Java Games: Active Rendering](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418) article. It properly synchronized with value of `JScrollBar` and size of `Canvas`. Also, it does painting directly to `Graphics`, obtained from `BufferStrategy` instance (instead of intermediate `BuffereImage` object). The result is something like this:

[image: Active Rendering Demo]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. JPanel does'nt have any BufferStrategy, that's why i'm using the frame to draw on. But your solution gives me a lot of options, cheers mate :)

Comment: Here is great [Java Games: Active Rendering](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418) article. It contains nice demo of Active Rendering with offscreen image. You would take rendering part as template, as it produces less overhead - rendering loop there contains really only required operations. Good luck :)

Comment: A problem emerged, I'm now using a canvas instead and read the article. However when i move my object, it stops rendering after the frame size(800x600). Meaning if i go with my object past 800 width and scroll further, it does'nt render there. Even though I'm drawing on the canvas with size 1400x600..

Comment: The canvas gets the size of the frame, even though it's getX() is correct. If i resize the frame, canvas updates to the new size if it is < MAX_X

Comment: Whole approach is wrong. `JScrolPane` can't correctly drive `Canvas`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: but AWT ScrollPane without blocking EDT by Thread.sleep() can do that

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing what i tried. Heavyweight `ScrollPane` with heavyweight `Canvas` - sounds good. But unfortunately, i see painting problems with one of scrollbars when the other one dissappears due to frame resizing. We want to use scroll pane to make things easy. But instead, it became source of problems. And I've made a decision to stop reinventing the wheel and use approach well-known in gamedev.

Comment: Nope, I also learned from this question a lot :) Few years ago i dreamed to make my game with similar rendering strategy. At least, now I've touched part of such game. PS. Later i will clean up answer and remove first wrong solution.

Comment: Glad to hear, you helped out a lot. Havent had time to experiment that much, hence I'm here. That JScrollPane flickering gave me nightmares

Comment: Btw, the use of imageOfGameField is quite unnecessary? Since i can use the graphics object to draw direct on canvas instead of putting the image on the canvas. Or is there any performance setbacks by that?

Comment: Honestly, i don't see any reason to use that image in such simple cases. Direct use of Graphics obtained from buffer strategy must be faster. But with image you can easily do some postprocessing (like smooth blackout after round finish, various artistic distortions, programmatic screenshot saving, or smth.). Generally, `BufferedImage` is useful for all pixel-level operations.

Comment: Well I've made some great changes to my engine, however I got a player object which i move around. I set the scrollbar to follow the player by adjusting the setValue to player position. However this makes the player flicker quite much when it's scrolling. Pretty cheap way of a camera implementation, but do you think it can be solved?

Comment: Take a look on second example. I have there "sprites" moving. Don't saw they flicks. Maybe you will get idea from code. Otherwise it is good reason to prepare new SSCCE and ask new question :) I'm afraid we violating rules of stackoverflow continuing discussion in old question.

Comment: Yeah maybe we are! My scroll is working fine if you scroll by yourself, but if you scroll by increasing setValue( int ) in the loop to follow the player, the flicker starts. So your example doesn't really help. This one is on me though, thanks again for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your game paints over your scroll pane
the resizing of the window shows your scroll pane for one moment because it the normal paint-method is called (no double-buffering)
you have some possibilities... the second one is prettier but it's your choice and i dont know what exactly you wanna do with it...

If you wanna control all the components in your jframe yourself:

- override the paint(Graphics g) method and just let it empty
- include the scrollpane-drawing in your paint-loop (method 'run')

If you wanna use double-buffering on another component that you dont have to manage other components directly with the double buffering.
The best component for this is the Canvas. It already has methods for double-buffering you can use.
Long time ago I made this, so i can't exactly tell you how it works. But just look it up, it isn't hard.

Comment: Do you mean overriding the JFrames paint or the JPanel (gameField)? And about the second option, i thought i was doing this by getting the image from the scroll, scroll.createImage(..)?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is manipulating Swing objects on a background thread. This will not work.

Read The [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Well everything draws up fine. I'm guessing this can give me future problems but it is'nt the main cause why the scrollbars arent shown.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller: Hasslam tries to utilize ["Active Rendering"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html) paradigm. Although is not so widely-spread as traditional Passive Rendering, but it works. Most caveats appearing when mixing usual Swing components with hand-made rendered components.

Comment: This is what I like about SO. I'm always learning something new! I hadn't realized "Active Rendering" bypassed the EDT rule.